# Tagging One Record with Another in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, tagging

I am attempting to create a model where an user can attach a record to an associated record through tagging in rails. I have this mostly functional however when I attempt to add a tag to an active record the tag is only added to the secondary record. For example, if I was trying to tag Record 2 to Record 1, it would instead tag Record 2 to Record 2. My current code is below:

RecordTagging Model

```
class Recordtagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :record
end
```

Record Controller

```
def record_params
        params.require(:record).permit(:name, :record_list, :record, { record_ids: [] }, :record_ids)
    end
```

Record Model

```
class Record < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :Recordtaggings
    has_many :records, through: :recordtaggings

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :name, uniqueness: true

    def self.recordtagged_with(name)
        Record.find_by!(name: name).records
    end

    def self.record_counts
        Record.select('records.*, count(recordtaggings.record_id) as count').joins(:recordtaggings).group('recordtaggings.record_id')
    end

    def record_list
        record.map(&:name).join(', ')
    end

    def record_list=(names)
        self.records = names.split(',').map do |n|
            Record.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
        end
    end
end
```

Record Show

```
<%= raw @record.records.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, records_path(t) }.join(', ') %>
```

Comment: I think the problem is here `Record.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!`. Is there a possibility that two records have the same name but you're only filtering by the first one? How are you creating the tags for each records? Is that al the code?

Answer (score 0):

To maintain a relation between Record object to another Record object, the middle man RecordTagging must have two fields specifying first record and second record. Here you have specified only one field record_id on RecordTagging, which tags a record to itself.

what you need is

```
class RecordTagging
   belongs_to record_1, class_name: 'Record', optional: true
   belongs_to record_2, class_name: 'Record', optional: true
end
```